# How do I replace card links color in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, hyperlink

How do I change the link color into this Bootstrap 4 card without affecting the link color of other cards on the same HTML page?

```css
/* I've tried this but it affects all cards on the HTML page: */

.card a:link {
  color: white;
}

.card a:visited {
  color: white;
}

.card a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card a:active {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card py-4 card-container">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="card-body">
        <i class="fa-light fa-book-open my-4" style="font-size: 36px"></i><br/>
        <p class="card-text text-center">CODE SAMPLES</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a textbook case for a custom class. You'd put it on the card you want to customize and write CSS accordingly. Or, use Bootstrap's [text color utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/colors/#color) to directly style your links with theme colors, which adds hover color shift automatically. I'll demonstrate both approaches here.

```css
.card.orangy a {
  color: orange;
}

.card.orangy a:hover,
.card.orangy a:active {
  color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card py-2 card-container">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <i class="fa-light fa fa-book-open mb-4" style="font-size: 36px"></i><br/>
            <p class="card-text text-center">Common card with no link styles</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card orangy py-2 card-container"> <!--------------- HERE -->
        <a href="#">
          <div class="card-body">
            <i class="fa-light fa fa-book-open mb-4" style="font-size: 36px"></i><br/>
            <p class="card-text text-center">Card with custom class</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card py-2 card-container">
        <a href="#" class="text-danger"> <!-------------------------- HERE -->
          <div class="card-body">
            <i class="fa-light fa fa-book-open mb-4" style="font-size: 36px"></i><br/>
            <p class="card-text text-center">Card with a text color class</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the code in your CSS file you need to change the focus color in `p` tag

```css
.card a:link {
  color: #333;
}

.card a:visited p {
  color: white;
}

.card a:hover p {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card a:active p {
  color: white;
}

.card a:focus p {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card py-4 card-container">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="card-body">
        <i class="fa-light fa-book-open my-4" style="font-size: 36px"></i><br/>
        <p class="card-text text-center">CODE SAMPLES</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to change the color of the font-awesome icon too, sorry.

Comment: You need to write the code for the icon also. See the code